# How would NLP handle semantic searches for spatial information?

Tags: python, search, text, nlp, semantics

Given a spatial related search phrase, such as *"Find cafes near the train station"*, what would be the approach to handling this with NLP / semantic searching?

In this case, would all the 'cafes' need to have a qualitative token with regard to their distance to the train station (e.g. near / far)? Curious to know what the thought process would be for handling these kind of tasks.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The way I would approach this is to look at the prepositions in the first place, in this case *near* means close by. You then identify the reference point (*train station*). Now you find *cafes* which are close to that, ie you should have a list of cafes with their coordinates, and you compare those against the coordinates of the train station, returning the ones that are closest.

Other prepositions (*opposite*) or other descriptions (*in the same street as*) would need corresponding other metrics to evaluate whether they fit.

This is not a semantic search problem, as there is nothing inherent in language that describes whether something is close or far from another thing -- you need to map this onto the 'world', and make a decision from non-linguistic data.